# Get selected file names in Dataview (extjs)

Tags: checkbox, extjs4, extjs4.1, selected, dataview

```
this.items[0].tpl = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '{[this.tempValue()]}',
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<tpl if="this.temp != title">',
            '<h3 class="dataview-title">{title}</h3>',
            '{[this.isTitle(values.title)]}',
        '</tpl>',
    '<div class="download-file">',
    '<input type="checkbox" value="{title}/{filename}"> ',
    '&nbsp;{filename}</div>',
    '</tpl>',
    '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
    {
        isTitle: function (title) {
            this.temp = title;
        },
        tempValue: function () {
            this.temp = '';
        }
    }
);
```

I have opened one popup window and showing some filenames with checkbox using Dataview template(**extjs-4.1.1**)In that I don't know, how to get the length of **selected file names**(checkBox selected items). Could you please explain me with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to query the DOM:

```
dv.el.select('input:checked').each(function(el){
    console.log(el.value);
});
```